# Shell filter for vary seperator

Tags: bash, shell

i m using transmission-remote which gives me back some data in the Following form.
Now i want to write a shell script file to filter out for example the id and the done percentage.
I don´t know if there`s a possibility to filter for the first number or something like that.I have problems using cut, because the separator " " can vary.

```
ID     Done       Have  ETA           Up    Down  Ratio  Status       Name
   2   100%   25.25 kB  Done         0.0     0.0    0.0  Idle         test
  34    90%    5.37 GB  Done         0.0     0.0    0.0  Idle         5gb
  37   100%    2.79 kB  Done         0.0     0.0    0.0  Idle         007.torrent
Sum:          21.22 GB               0.0     0.0
```

Comment: What do you mean 'the separator " " can vary'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
$ awk '$1~/^[0-9]+$/ && $2~/^[0-9]/{print $1,$2}' file
2 100%
34 90%
37 100%
```